# Selenium Grid showing issues by upload images in between hod and node machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use grid:-

I can't upload images from local machine to remort/node machine.

*I have used `.sendkey()`
*i have used `robot()`
*i have use `autoit`

but I can't get any result.

The scenario is, this is a Chrome browser, there is an upload button when the user clicks on the upload button, he shall upload one image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1l9h.png)

Comment: Please post the code in the question.

Comment: Your code trials please.

Comment: `((RemoteWebDriver)driver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement upload1_1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='uploadsalfile1']"));
    upload1_1.click();
    Thread.sleep(4000l);
    upload1_1.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\S_ADMIN\\Desktop\\images.jpg");
    `

Comment: `autoit`
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\newopen.exe");